# Please Help - Salesforce crashing on iOS 15

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, ios

Recently we started to seeing many crash logs in our iOS app and the crash-free rate significantly dropped. If someone has similar problem or able to help will be greatly appreciated.

I will attach the stack trace and more info below:

`Thread 0 name: Thread 0 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020d73b464 __terminate_with_payload + 8 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020d73cc44 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 136 (terminate_with_reason.c:106) 2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020d73cbbc abort_with_reason + 32 (terminate_with_reason.c:116) 3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ee85f0b4 _objc_fatalv(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, char const*, char*) + 116 (objc-errors.mm:202) 4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ee85f040 _objc_fatal(char const*, ...) + 32 (objc-errors.mm:218) 5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ee837acc weak_register_no_lock + 392 (objc-weak.mm:422) 6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ee83c924 objc_storeWeak + 448 (NSObject.mm:363) 7   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d7f55a94 -[_UIRootPresentationController initWithPresentedViewController:presentingWindow:] + 108 (_UIRootPresentationController.m:24) 8   UIKitCore                       0x00000001d81cec78 -[UIWindow setRootViewController:] + 484 (UIWindow.m:2399) 9   SalesforceSDKCore               0x000000010142276c -[SFSDKUIWindow disableWindow] + 228 (SFSDKWindowManager.m:628) 10  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8ff05e8 __138-[UIWindowScene _evaluateSceneKeyWindowForWindowMadeKey:consideringVisibility:findingNewKeyWindowIfNeeded:ignoringOldKeyWindow:forReason:]_block_invoke.535 + 132 (UIWindowScene.m:1209) 11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d80d296c -[_UIKeyWindowEvaluator _evaluateApplicationKeyWindowWithComparisonWindowScene:changingKeyWindowSceneActions:sceneKeyWindowActions:ignoringOldKeyWindow:sceneResignKeyWindowActions:andSceneBecomeKey... + 996 (_UIKeyWindowEvaluator.m:559) 12  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d81437bc -[_UIKeyWindowEvaluator evaluateApplicationKeyWindowForWindowScene:withWindowMadeKey:sceneKeyWindowActions:ignoringOldKeyWindow:sceneResignKeyWindowActions:andSceneBecomeKeyWindowActions:forReason:] + 288 (_UIKeyWindowEvaluator.m:652) 13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d80e35fc -[UIWindowScene _evaluateSceneKeyWindowForWindowMadeKey:consideringVisibility:findingNewKeyWindowIfNeeded:ignoringOldKeyWindow:forReason:] + 1868 (UIWindowScene.m:1182) 14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d81583bc -[UIWindowScene _windowUpdatedVisibility:] + 576 (UIWindowScene.m:1080) 15  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8117878 -[UIWindow _updateLayerOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:actionBlock:] + 204 (UIWindow.m:0) 16  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d815e9c8 -[UIWindow dealloc] + 480 (UIWindow.m:1411) 17  libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00000002473f9804 _Block_release + 192 (runtime.cpp:176) 18  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d822695c -[_UIAfterCACommitBlock run] + 84 (_UIAfterCACommitQueue.m:154) 19  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8139b4c -[_UIAfterCACommitQueue flush] + 192 (_UIAfterCACommitQueue.m:228) 20  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d806323c _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 644 (UIApplication.m:3038) 21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8063960 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 132 (UIApplication.m:3002) 22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d843c6ec _UIApplicationFlushCATransaction + 84 (UIApplication.m:3079) 23  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d86d6d5c _UIUpdateSequenceRun + 84 (_UIUpdateSequence.mm:112) 24  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8d5dedc schedulerStepScheduledMainSection + 144 (_UIUpdateScheduler.m:778) 25  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8d5d6a4 runloopSourceCallback + 92 (_UIUpdateScheduler.m:870) 26  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d5b3b414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1972) 27  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d5b4c1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208 (CFRunLoop.c:2016) 28  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d5a856f8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:2061) 29  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d5a8b05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828 (CFRunLoop.c:2951) 30  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001d5a9ebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600 (CFRunLoop.c:3268) 31  GraphicsServices                0x00000001f1c09374 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2200) 32  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8412b58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100 (UIApplication.m:3511) 33  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d8194090 UIApplicationMain + 364 (UIApplication.m:5064) 34  bnf                             0x0000000100653e4c main + 192 (main.swift:13) 35  dyld`

[image: iOS crash log image]

[image: crash image details]

Comment: What is the app version? Came across this related [KI](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002dlXTQAY&title=salesforce-for-ios-app-crashes-on-version-236-060-ios-version-15-5)

Comment: We using cocoa pods Salesforce Mobile SDK 9.2.1 in our project @Swetha. Thank you!

Comment: Any updates here? I'm getting a similar crash on my project

Comment: Ah I've found that https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/3536 appears to be the fix to this. Thanks